# Call PHP Wordpress shortcode - Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am using wordpress and 2 plugins called unyson and brizy.
Basically unyson provides me a shortcode I want to call trough the front page builder brizy on my homepage.

I want to call the portfolio shortcode with [portfolio]
This works.

Live website: https://xprs.ch/
Under "Our Work Portfolio"

Now I want to add options:
[portfolio page_link="On" categories="website"]

As long as I just define page_link it works.
But as soon as I try to define the categories I get the following error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /home/httpd/vhosts/xprs.ch/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/jevelin/framework-customizations/extensions/shortcodes/shortcodes/portfolio/views/view.php on line 100
```

I also get above error if just defining categories so I need to define this different but how?

The code from the shortcode:
NOTE: I cannot change this code.
I need to pass the parameter "website" correctly in the front end.

```
$options = array(

    'id' => array( 'type' => 'unique' ),
    'general' => array(
        'title'   => esc_html__( 'General', 'jevelin' ),
        'type'    => 'tab',
        'options' => array(

            'style' => array(
                'type'    => 'radio',
                'label'   => esc_html__('Style', 'jevelin'),
                'desc'  => esc_html__('Choose main style', 'jevelin'),
                'choices' => array(
                    'default' => esc_html__('Standard', 'jevelin'),
                    'default-shadow' => esc_html__('Standard with Shadow', 'jevelin'),
                    'default2' => esc_html__('Trendy', 'jevelin'),
                    'masonry' => esc_html__('Gallery', 'jevelin'),
                    'masonry2' => esc_html__('Marginless Gallery', 'jevelin'),
                    'minimalistic' => esc_html__('Minimalistic', 'jevelin'),
                ),
                'value'   => 'default',
            ),

            'categories' => array(
                'type'  => 'multi-select',
                'label' => esc_html__('Categories', 'jevelin'),
                'desc'  => esc_html__('Select categories', 'jevelin'),
                'population' => 'taxonomy',
                'source' => 'fw-portfolio-category',
                'prepopulate' => 200,
                'limit' => 100,
            ),

            'page_link' => array(
                'type' => 'switch',
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Page Link', 'jevelin' ),
                'desc' => esc_html__( 'Enable or disable portfolio page link', 'jevelin' ),
                'value' => true,
                'left-choice' => array(
                    'value' => false,
                    'label' => esc_html__('Off', 'jevelin'),
                ),
                'right-choice' => array(
                    'value' => true,
                    'label' => esc_html__('On', 'jevelin'),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
);
```

How do I need to call categories?

Comment: _“The code from the shortcode”_ - that is basically just configuration data, no one here knows what is done with that data. If either one of those plugins provides this short code, then it should provide documentation on how to use it as well, no? If it does not work as described, then you should perhaps rather ask the plugin author for support.

Comment: First of all, you are not getting an error, you are getting a *Warning*.  When you turn off error reporting, this will not display.  Secondly: Show us the code _that throws the warning_.  The code you've shared clearly is not what is causing the warning. Lastly: if the code you are asking about is in your the plugin, and you can't change it, what is it you expect us to do for you here?

Answer (score -2):

Here:

```
$cats = array();
foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) {
    $cats[] = $cat->cat_ID;
}
$args = array(
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'field'            => 'id',
            'terms'            => $cats,
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
);
print_r( WP_Query( $args ) as $post );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I cannot change the existing shortcode code. I have to enter the shortcode correctly in the frontend as text [portfolio categories="website"]
I need to know how to pass the category website as example

Comment: You can't edit your shortcode but you can try array_merge, create another array and merge it with the old one as new variable.